# jQuery overlay a div over a forum field

Tags: jquery, css

Lets say I made a big form.
Let one element of the form be like this :

```
<form>
...

<tr>
<td><div id="username"><input name="username" id="username" type="text"/></div></td>
</tr>

...
</form>
```

Now I placed a div at the bottom something like this:

```
<div id="submiter">Submit</div>
```

Now I have this js:

```
$("#submiter").click(function() {
    $.post("submiter.php",
        $("#formmain").serialize(),
        function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(){
          id=thisid;
          error=this.error;
          //want some code here to over lay div with the id got with this.id
        }) },'json')
});
```

Now the php returns json in this format

> [{id:formelementid,error:The error}]

**Question**:
How to overlay **completely** a div with class `errors` with the errors in it for simplicity let the div be `#username`?
A demo would be very nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS question:

```
.errors {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2; /* Or higher than parent div */
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFF; /* Whatever */
}
```

If you want to append this div with JQuery, use [append<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('<div class="errors"/>').appendTo('#my_form');
```

In your example, it would work like so:

```
$("#submiter").click(function() {
    $.post("submiter.php",
        $("#formmain").serialize(),
        function(data) {
            var errors = '';
            $.each(data,function(){
                id=thisid;
                error=this.error;
                errors += error + '<br />'; 
            });
            $('<div class="errors"/>').appendTo('#my_form').html(errors); 
        },'json')
});
```

To make the overlay go away when the user wants it to, simply apply a click handler:

```
$('.errors').live('click',function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: You forgot to select JQuery in the left menu :)

Comment: yea but now i did but still doesnt works the way i want see this :http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/qdKAk/5/

Comment: It appends over the button but i want it overlay the input feild

Comment: Ah that's different completely bro. You can't add DOM nodes inside an `<input />`. You really *don't* want to do that. Just modify the style of the label: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/qdKAk/7/

Comment: This means we cant put a div overlay an input ? :O

Comment: It's not valid HTML. If you want the input to look like the errors div, just use this: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/qdKAk/10/